# How can I show progress while canvas is resizing an image?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How can I get progress information, that is.

I want to show a progress bar eventually but this question is basically only about the progress information per se. How I render it is irrelevant.

Comment: Resizing an image on a canvas element occurs so quickly that you won't need a progress bar. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. The API for canvas does not support any mechanism to retrieve progress information from it.

It is a single threaded operation as well which means such information could not be utilized in any case, as your script would halt and not being able to perform anything while waiting for the process to finish.

It all happens internally, and usually so fast that there is no need for progress information. As canvas' bitmap is limited in size your images will not be so big that this becomes an UX problem (unless this is a very unusual scenario, or running on outdated hardware etc.).